# Create a vector of closures from any type to any other type

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to create a vector of functions, the idea is that the output of the 1st function will get piped into the input of the second function, etc, etc.

I'm having a hard time understanding how (if it's possible) to encode this into the Rust type system. I tried using generics but ran into issues because generics expect that the input and output will always be the same for each element in the vector of functions.

For example, function one may be `i32 -> String`, function two `String -> bool` and function three `bool -> f64`.

My attempt:

```
fn main() {
    let mut funcs: Vec<Box<Fn(i32) -> i32>> = Vec::new();

    funcs.push(Box::new(|a| a * 2));
    funcs.push(Box::new(|b| b * 3));

    // This won't work since it's not a Fn(i32) -> i32
    funcs.push(Box::new(|c| String::from(c)));

    // How can I create a vec of Fn(anything) -> anything where the anythings can be different for every item in the vector?
}
```

I'm beginning to think the only way this is possible in Rust would be a struct with a specific amount of elements created with a macro.

Comment: Why does this need to be stored in a `Vec`? That seems to be the core of the conflict here. `Vec` is by definition a list of items with the same type, making it a bad fit for what you want.

Comment: @loganfsmyth What other type of collection could I use? I want a struct to have a collection of functions

Comment: If your goal is to create a chain of functions that feed together, you could for instance return a new function that composes the two functions together, avoiding the collection entirely. A collection is not a good data structure for a composed chain of functions. If your goal is to take the collection and call each function in order, better to just make the structure store an function that will call the chain, so the struct would just know the input and output type of the full chain.

Comment: *from any type to any other type* — And what happens when the output **doesn't** match the subsequent input?

Comment: @loganfsmyth The reason I can't use chained functions is I'm trying to do this chain of functions multithreaded. There is an input of 100 items, and then each all the transformations from one item to the next are done concurrently because some are much faster than others.

Comment: You said `output of the 1st function will get piped into the input of the second function` though right? So if you've got 100 inputs, that means there are 100 full calls to your chain to run, is that right? Can't you just start N threads with the first N items, and then work your way through the rest of the items as previous ones finish? I'm still not clear on why you'd need the separate steps to be their own items, rather than treating the chain itself as a single item with an input and output type.

Comment: @loganfsmyth The first step is really quick, so I will only be using 1 thread in practice. The first step is literally iterating numbers. The second step requires making one web request which gives me 10 links. The third step is visiting every single one of the 10 links. The idea was I would have 1 thread for the first step, 2 for the second, and 20 for the third step. Actually building this is not too hard, but I'm trying to build a pipeline abstraction over this proccess.

Comment: I feel like you might have been better off asking your question with that as the details. This feels like a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. I understand the issue you want to solve, but a Vec just isn't a great way to solve that. You've got an answer here for the specific question you asked, using `Any`, but for a real solution to your problem the answer is don't use a Vec. I personally find event loops easy to follow which would address your real goal, but there are probably a bunch of ways to think about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) trait in a `Box`, but:

- You'll get runtime errors if the types don't match instead of compile time errors
- Performance will probably suck

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=479dbe1909855d77054381f6cd82b6d9&version=stable)

```
use std::any::Any;

pub type FnAnyToAny = Fn(Box<Any>) -> Box<Any>;

pub fn make_any_to_any<I, O, F>(f: F) -> Box<FnAnyToAny>
where
    I: 'static,
    O: 'static,
    F: Fn(I) -> O + 'static,
{
    Box::new(move |i: Box<Any>| -> Box<Any> {
        let i: Box<I> = Box::<Any + 'static>::downcast(i).expect("wrong input type");
        Box::new(f(*i))
    })
}

pub fn run_all_any<I, O>(funcs: &Vec<Box<FnAnyToAny>>, i: I) -> O
where
    I: 'static,
    O: 'static,
{
    let i: Box<Any> = Box::new(i);
    let o = funcs.iter().fold(i, |acc, f| f(acc));
    let o: Box<O> = Box::<Any + 'static>::downcast(o).expect("wrong output type");
    *o
}

fn main() {
    let mut funcs: Vec<Box<FnAnyToAny>> = Vec::new();

    funcs.push(make_any_to_any(|a: i32| a * 2));
    funcs.push(make_any_to_any(|b: i32| b * 3));

    funcs.push(make_any_to_any(|c: i32| format!("{}", c)));

    println!("{:?}", run_all_any::<i32, String>(&funcs, 4));
}
```

In the comments you mentioned you actually want to process lots of input items and run each function in a separate thread. I think the [`rayon`](https://crates.io/crates/rayon) crate should handle this just fine:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4e5adf4745305505c61c121c27eba4de&version=stable)

```
extern crate rayon;
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let input = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    // without parallel processing you'd start with:
    // let output = input.into_iter()
    let output = input
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(|a| a * 2)
        .map(|b| b * 3)
        .map(|c| format!("{}", c))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    println!("{:?}", output);
}
```

If you actually wait a lot e.g. for network data (instead of actually requiring CPU time) you might want to take a look at the [`futures`](https://crates.io/crates/futures) crate, especially [`futures::stream::Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html).